# Arangodb: can I use a subquery to determine starting node for graph traversal

Tags: subquery, arangodb

I am using arangodb to build a permissions system.

I would like to use a subquery to determine starting node for a graph traversal.  This is what I attempted

```
FOR vert IN 1..5
  OUTBOUND (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..2
      OUTBOUND 'users/jill'
      GranterGrant, GrantGrantee
      FILTER e.edgeType == 'GrantGrantee' 
        AND v.type == 'User' 
        AND v._id == 'users/jim'
      LIMIT 1
      RETURN p.vertices[1]
  )
  RolePrivilege, GrantRole, GrantPrivilege
  FILTER vert.type == 'Privilege' 
    AND vert._id == 'privileges/JournalRead'
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN vert._id
```

The inner query is meant to find a permissions grant node from `jill` to `jim`, and the outer query determines if there is a path from the grant node to the privilege `JournalRead`

The subquery works when run by itself, and returns a vertex that I would like to use as the starting node for the outer query.  The outer query works if I hard code the starting node.

However, when I run the entire query above, arango responds with

```
Warnings:

[10], 'Invalid input for traversal: Only id strings or objects with _id are allowed'

Result:

[]
```

Note, I also tried `RETURN p.vertices[1]._id` within the subquery with the same outcome.

So, is it possible to use a subquery to determine the starting node of a graph traversal?

Answer (score 1):

You can to get the list of starting nodes first and assign them to a variable instead of using a subquery.
So in you case, it would be something like:

```
let initialNodes = (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..2
      OUTBOUND 'users/jill'
      GranterGrant, GrantGrantee
      FILTER e.edgeType == 'GrantGrantee' 
        AND v.type == 'User' 
        AND v._id == 'users/jim'
      LIMIT 1
      RETURN p.vertices[1]
  )
FOR initialNode IN initialNodes
  FOR vert IN 1..5
    OUTBOUND initialNode
    RolePrivilege, GrantRole, GrantPrivilege
    FILTER vert.type == 'Privilege' 
      AND vert._id == 'privileges/JournalRead'
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN vert._id
```

Note that you are not limited to a single initial node. You can return multiple one in the subquery if needed.

Comment: just to add to this answer, since the subquery is returning vertices then avoid using path p in the query for optimization purposes. It will look like this

 FOR v, e IN 1..2